# position absolute top minimum 40% AND 320px

Tags: css, sass

Is there any way I can set my absolute position top to minimum 40% AND 320px.

If my page becomes too low, my div needs to keep a minimum height of 320px, which will be more than 40%.

If my page becomes higher, it needs the minimum height of 40%, which will be more than 320px.

```css
.class {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  top: 320px;
}
```

Comment: Checkout media query. Should be something you are looking for. Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: the question isn't quite clear, because `top:` is position, not height

Comment: @Banzay as I understood, he means height of window

Comment: media query works like a charm, didn't realize you could use them for height as well, thx!

Comment: I think it should work without media queries: https://jsfiddle.net/6psmt8a2/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Probably your code shoud be something like this:

```
@media (max-height: 400px) {
  .class {
    position: absolute;
    top: 320px;
  }
}

@media (min-height: 401px) {
   .class {
     position: absolute;
     top: 40%;
   }
}
```

Comment: You could simplify the code by swapping queries and removing `@media (min-height: 401px)` as redundant statement and just leaving its content. Thus class with `top: 40%;` will work everytime unless it will be overrided by media query for `max-height: 400px`

Comment: @Banzay yup, you are right. But it's just an example of media-query usage.  By the way, using "master" styles, which will rewritten with media query - it's a good habit. Thanks.